# How does grub2 find its configuration file in EFI boot?

Tags: grub2, uefi

There are bazillions of grub2/EFI threads on the net, but I found it difficult to find out how grub2 finds its configuration file in EFI boot. We have been told that in grub2 the configuration file is `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. But when there are boot problems grub2 might end up in a command prompt (aka emergency shell) without any error message. So before being able to solve any problems it would be nice to understand how grub2 exactly tries to locate its configuration file.

Answer (score 10):

The first thing to understand that there is no fixed way. 
grub2 can be configured differently during installation,
and the name `grub.cfg` is not hard-coded. 
The second learning is that there is no single configuration file,
e.g., my Ubuntu system at the time of writing uses two different files in sequence,
both actually named `grub.cfg`.

By default, grub2 does two essential things when starting:

1. set the prefix variable to a value built-in during grub2 installation
2. continue with configuration file `$prefix/grub.cfg` if it exists

(For more details, refer to [the GNU GRUB Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#GRUB-only-offers-a-rescue-shell).)

The "if it exists" condition is the nasty one: If the file does not exist
(e.g., because `$prefix` is not pointing to the right place), there is no
error message what it tried to do, and you just end up in the command prompt.

If you end up in the emergency shell, the first things to check are the
value of the prefix variable (using set command) and the contents of
that directory (using ls and cat commands).

(The default behaviour could be overwritten by a built-in
configuration file, but I don't think I have seen that used in
practice.)

Ubuntu sets the prefix to the same place where the `grubx64.efi` and the `shimx64.efi` used for secure boot are located. So the first
configuration file grub.cfg is loaded from the same directory where
these EFI binaries reside. From Linux perspective, the path is
`/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu` and from grub2 perspective `(hd0,gpt1)/efi/ubuntu`
(the drive and partition numbers might vary depending on where your
ESP, i.e., EFI system partition, is located. 
Filenames in grub2 seem to be case-insensitive,
so the EFI shown by Linux is shown as `efi` by grub2).

The first `grub.cfg` file contains only 3 statements:

1. locate the partition containing the root file system by UUID (in
   systems using a separate boot file system locate the boot file system
   instead)
2. set prefix to a new value of `$root/boot/grub` (using the
   `$root` value determined in the previous step, for systems with a
   separate boot partition this should be `$root/grub`)
3. execute the `configfile` from location `$prefix/grub.cfg`

The latter is the Linux location `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, which we are usually told.

Comment: its pretty good information, but why do you put up w/ all that jazz? why not just uninstall it?